# Laravel graceful end event-listener within a request

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-7

Within my controller I am creating a message which then fires an event after a successful message create:

```
public function store(Conversation $conversation, Request $request)
{
    $message = Message::create(...)
       
    event(new MessageCreated($message));

    return response([
        'message' => $message,
    ]);
}
```

Now the event has a few listeners on it, one of which checks if it can send a message over external provider. What I am doing within a listener is throwing an error if something fails.

I don't understand how could an exception trace of a listener come as a response to `POST /message` request since I am returning right after an event. Following on that, I would like to return a custom response if something fails so I can fail gracefully, and surely enough this works:

```
try {
    event(new MessageCreated($message));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return 'failed';
}
```

But...why does it work? It seems very wrong. Is there a more standard way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your code I assume this is not an queued event. In that case the execution on this event is not async but sync.

By that I mean that execution goes all the was to your
`event(new MessageCreated($message));`
then "summons" (so to speak) a piece of code (in your case MessageCreated($message)) which then throws an exception. However that exception is caught in your handler (App\Exceptions\Handler) and returned as a 500 server error.

You can catch those exceptions there and ignore them or you can go with what is written in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events#defining-listeners

Stopping The Propagation Of An Event

> Sometimes, you may wish to stop the propagation of an event to other listeners. You may do so by returning false from your listener's handle method.